# How remove duplicate item by a property value in a List<>

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me take this Linq query and show me how to pull out the Distinct product Names

```
List<StatePlan> planTypes = (from ppt in context.PlanPlanTypes
     join pt in context.PlanTypes on ppt.PlanTypeRowID equals pt.PlanTypeRowID
     join ppts in context.PlanPlanTypeStates on ppt.PlanPlanTypeRowID equals ppts.PlanPlanTypeRowID
     join p in context.Plans on ppt.PlanRowID equals p.PlanRowID
     where ppts.StateCode == stateCode
     where p.IsActive == true
     select new StatePlan
     {   
         PlanID = p.PlanRowID,
         StateCode = stateCode,
         Name = p.Name,
         Description = p.Description,
         Disclaimer = p.Disclaimer,
         Sequence = p.DisplaySequence,
         //Rates = GetRates(p.PlanRowID),
         //Types = GetPlanTypes(p.PlanRowID, stateCode)
     }).ToList();
return planTypes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group it first then take the first

```
List<StatePlan> planTypes = (from ppt in context.PlanPlanTypes
                                             join pt in context.PlanTypes on ppt.PlanTypeRowID equals pt.PlanTypeRowID
                                             join ppts in context.PlanPlanTypeStates on ppt.PlanPlanTypeRowID equals ppts.PlanPlanTypeRowID
                                             join p in context.Plans on ppt.PlanRowID equals p.PlanRowID
                                             where ppts.StateCode == stateCode
                                             where p.IsActive == true
                                             select new StatePlan
                                             {   
                                                 PlanID = p.PlanRowID,
                                                 StateCode = stateCode,
                                                 Name = p.Name,
                                                 Description = p.Description,
                                                 Disclaimer = p.Disclaimer,
                                                 Sequence = p.DisplaySequence,
                                                 //Rates = GetRates(p.PlanRowID),
                                                 //Types = GetPlanTypes(p.PlanRowID, stateCode)
                                             })
                                             .GroupBy(g => g.Name)
                                             .Select(s => s.First())
                                             .ToList();
            return planTypes;
```

Comment: This worked great, however, I did need to change to s.FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @JonHarding Why did you need that change? I would expect each group to have at least one element.

Comment: This was the error thrown: "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead." I tried the suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if you want items that have a certain distinct field, you can use groupby+first:

```
seq.GroupBy(item=>item.Name).Select(group=>group.First())
```

You could also use a projection equality comparer, but I consider that a bit ugly. For me using `Distinct` implies that you don't care which of the equivalent items you get. Whereas groupby+first explicitly states that you want the first one.

GroupBy also allows you to collect additional information in your `Select` clause, for example how many items with such a name exist.

---

If you only want the distinct names without the associated item, combine select and distinct:

```
seq.Select(item=>item.Name).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
planTypes.Select(pt=>pt.Name).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Call `Distinct` and provide and IEqualityComparer for `StatePlan`

[Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the product name is the `Name` property in the `planTypes` list, and that it is a string:

```
List<string> productNames = planTypes.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```